# vtkCharts library doesn't work neither with Visual Studio nor with GCC compiler - Why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visualization, data-visualization, vtk

I'm a newbie to vtk and I want to use the vtkCharts library. In both Linux and Windows, I compiled vtk and managed to work with the most of the examples.

The only troublesome examples arre those including the chart library, such as the one in the link:

[Line plot example](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Plotting/LinePlot)

When I compile, in Visual Studio it gives some linking errors. A segment is below. I didn't forget to include the vtkCharts library.

> 1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "protected: virtual __thiscall
>   vtkRenderView::~vtkRenderView(void)"
>   (??1vtkRenderView@@MAE@XZ) referenced
>   in function "protected: virtual
>   __thiscall vtkContextView::~vtkContextView(void)"
>   (??1vtkContextView@@MAE@XZ)
>   1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: virtual void
>   __thiscall vtkRenderView::SetDisplayHoverText(bool)"
>   (?SetDisplayHoverText@vtkRenderView@@UAEX_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "protected:
>   __thiscall vtkContextView::vtkContextView(void)"
>   (??0vtkContextView@@IAE@XZ)
>   1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "protected: __thiscall
>   vtkRenderView::vtkRenderView(void)"
>   (??0vtkRenderView@@IAE@XZ) referenced
>   in function "protected: __thiscall
>   vtkContextView::vtkContextView(void)"
>   (??0vtkContextView@@IAE@XZ)
>   1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: virtual void
>   __thiscall vtkView::Update(void)" (?Update@vtkView@@UAEXXZ)
>   1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: virtual void
>   __thiscall vtkRenderView::ApplyViewTheme(class
>   vtkViewTheme *)"
>   (?ApplyViewTheme@vtkRenderView@@UAEXPAVvtkViewTheme@@@Z)
>   1>vtkCharts.lib(vtkContextView.obj) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol "protected: virtual void
>   __thiscall vtkRenderView::ProcessEvents(class
>   vtkObject *,unsigned long,void *)"
>   (?ProcessEvents@vtkRenderView@@MAEXPAVvtkObject@@KPAX@Z)

In Code::Blocks , using GCC, it gives errors like this:

> ./VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|38|error:
>   expected class-name before ‘{’ token|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error:
>   ‘vtkContextItem’ does not name a type|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error:
>   ‘vtkContextItem’ has not been
>   declared|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error:
>   invalid static_cast from type
>   ‘vtkObjectBase*’ to type ‘vtkChart*’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In
>   member function ‘virtual
>   vtkObjectBase*
>   vtkChart::NewInstanceInternal()
>   const’:|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|40|error:
>   ‘New’ is not a member of ‘vtkChart’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In
>   member function ‘virtual
>   vtkAnnotationLink*
>   vtkChart::GetAnnotationLink()’:|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|104|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetDebug’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|104|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|104|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In
>   member function ‘virtual void
>   vtkChart::SetGeometry(int, int)’:|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|108|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetDebug’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|108|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|108|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|108|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘Modified’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In
>   member function ‘virtual int*
>   vtkChart::GetGeometry()’:|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|109|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetDebug’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|109|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|109|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetClassName’|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h||In
>   member function ‘virtual void
>   vtkChart::GetGeometry(int&, int&)’:|
>   ../VTK-build/VTK-5.6/VTK/Charts/vtkChart.h|109|error:
>   ‘class vtkChart’ has no member named
>   ‘GetDebug’|

I'm using vtk 5-6 in both platforms. I wonder the reasons why this error might occur.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't forget to include the vtkCharts library.

Then you probably forgot to include the vtkHybrid library.  Note the last line in the cmake file.

Comment: No it's also included. But I noticed that I didn't build vtk with examples. Does the chart library comes completely only with examples?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.